How convert reactJs component into pdf and share this pdf on Whatsapp
I want to convert my reactjs component into a PDF, and then the generated PDF needs to be shared on WhatsApp using the share WhatsApp button.
I have one button in my component, "Share on Whatsapp." On clicking this button, I want to convert my bill component into a PDF and share this PDF on WhatsApp.
const shareOnWhatsApp = async () => {
    try {
      const element = billRef.current;
      const canvas = await html2canvas(element);
      const data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

      const pdf = new jsPDF("portrait", "px", [380, 380]);

      const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
      const pdfHeight = pdf.internal.pageSize.getHeight();

      pdf.addImage(data, "PNG", 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
      const pdfUrl = pdf.output("blob");
      const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfUrl);
      const whatsappLink = `https://wa.me/+91xxxxxxxxxx?document=${encodeURIComponent(
        blobUrl
      )}`;
      console.log(whatsappLink, pdfUrl, blobUrl);
      window.open(whatsappLink, "_blank");

      console.log("PDF shared successfully on WhatsApp!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error generating or sharing PDF:", error);
    }
  };

